# How to turn on another lamp across room with lightswitch that only controls a one outlet?

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, smart-switch, cable-management

In my office I have a light switch that only controls the bottom plug on one outlet.  I have a lamp plugged into it, but I'd like to be able to have another lamp plugged into it also.

Right now that only way I can see doing this is to have a long extension cord from that outlet that reaches to a point where I can plug both lamps into it, like this:

[image: Room - extension cord layout]

This can work, but it will be kind of ugly with the cables everywhere.

Instead is there some kind of device that exists that I can plug into the light switch controlled outlet that will wirelessly toggle a linked device on an always-on outlet?

I suppose it might be similar to those WiFi things you can plug lamps into, but instead of WiFi it just gets it's signal to turn on/off from the device plugged into the other outlet. Does that make sense?  Here's the setup I'd envision for this:

[image: Room - wireless layout]

Comment: *In my office* Is this an office in a commercial building? Or a spare room in your private single-family home? Big difference because in a commercial building in almost all places you really need to use a licensed electrician. In many (not all) places in your own home you can do basic wiring yourself.

Comment: It's a home office, but I'm not asking about doing anything needing an electrician at all. I'm asking for a device similar to a wifi plug that I can use to control power to another outlet.  Like, you plug it in to the outlet and then plug the outlet into that.

Comment: Yes there is such a beast,

Comment: Kasa smart switch with a couple of smart outlets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this device will do what your asking. When you turn on your outlet operated by a switch it will automatically turn on light on the non-switched outlet. You can link multiple devices.
[https://www.amazon.com/Switcheroo-Easy-Home-Lighting-Automation/dp/B07BX6QF7Q?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BX6QF7Q)
[image]

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I hoped existed, thank you!  Wow that's a **lot** more expensive than I was expecting though!

Comment: It is a volume vs. functions issues. There are other switches/gadgets in a similar price range that include far more functionality but not necessarily *this* functionality, and certainly not as plug-n-play simple. But those other gadgets are manufactured in the 10s or 100s of 1,000s and this in a much smaller volume, so the manufacturer doesn't have the same economy of scale.

Comment: If you want to do it cheaper use a couple of $5 smart outlets and the controller of your choice .. Flic, Alexa or whatever.  Also if you use one cord to the first lamp and a second cord from there to the second behind the desk, I don't think that'll look worse than using both outlets.

Comment: @jay613 yeah that's true and it may be what I end up doing simple just for the price difference.  It's a standing desk, so any wires are a lot more visible than normal so I just wanted to minimize what I can see.  Perhaps I can try to tuck the wires between the carpet and baseboard for now and then "upgrade" in the future if I need to.

Comment: Wires under carpet is a bit of a cliché fire hazard. :(   Unless you use low voltage lamps with external PSUs, then you can run the LV wire however you want.  New lamps will obviously cost a lot of money, but then you can get ones with up and down lights and color changing ... good fun.

Answer (score 5):

Other answer was exactly what you need but for the same cost you can get lutron caseta setup which is much better.  Replace wall switch with Lutron caseta dimmer, this will control wired switch outlet. Get plug wall outlet switch. With the hub you can program them all together and you have a wireless remote for desk plus voice/app control.

[Lutron Wireless Lighting P-PKG1-P-WH-Assistant at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JJY1QG0)

[Lutro Wireless Lighting P-BDG-PKG1W-Assistant at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MXCRAX8)

Comment: Using the Lutron Caseta family of devices is surely the best way to do this. There can be some concern when using a Dimmer type switch to control a switched outlet. The reason being that the switched outlet could have other type things plugged into it at one time or another and running some devices like this could fry the dimmer or the device. I see two solutions to this. One would use a better on/off type switch such as this kit: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08FRN8FK5?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details. <continued>

Comment: <from previous> The other possibility is to just get two of the plug-in lamp dimmer module kits. At the switched outlet the lamp dimmer module can plug into the always live part of the outlet and then you can get the Pico remote wall mount kit to allow mounting the remote near the door into the room. The Pico remote would be paired to both of the lamp dimmer modules. This solution eliminates any need to open any electrical boxes or mess with any of the house wiring.